# Is there a geometrical/mathematical way of finding this out?

Tags: area

[image]

Basically I need to find out what are the tiles affected by the area projected by the 2 lines, is there maybe a function or something like that to get that information?.

Comment: While your picture is evocative, let me suggest that you write a precise mathematical desciption. *What are the tiles affected by the area projected by the 2 lines* is not sufficiently precise. You should be able to easily make it precise by using coordinates, and equations for the lines, and mathematical conditions on the rectangles in question.

Comment: You might also want to read the portion of our [formatting and writing guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992), under the heading *Make your question visible, searchable, accessible*.

Comment: And you might also profit from reading the meta post [Why image cannot be used for explaining my maths problem?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem/34123#34123).

Comment: I honestly dont think there is anything else that is needed to be added in order to properly convey what Im looking for, the squares can just be defined as a NxN square in a X,Y arbitrary location.

Comment: Let me again suggest you read carefully that post for why images cannot be used. Meanwhile, I'll vote to close.

Comment: Do you know the exact equations of the two lines?  At first glance, it looks like $y = 2x - 1$ and $y = \frac{3}{2}x - 3$ (with the origin at the lower left corner), but on closer inspection, the slope of the left line is not exactly 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given two lines defined by the equations $y = a_1 x + b_1$ and $y = a_2 x + b_2$, you seem to want the squares with vertices $(X,Y)$, $(X+1,Y)$, $(X+1,Y+1)$ and $(X,Y+1)$, $X$ and $Y$ integers, such that at least one vertex is (strictly) below the first line and at least one is (strictly) above the second.
Thus
$$ \eqalign{\min(Y - a_1 X - b_1, Y - a_1 (X+1) - b_1) &< 0 \cr
            \max(Y+1 - a_2 X - b_2, Y+1 - a_2 (X+1) - b_2) &> 0 \cr} $$
If $a_1 > 0$ and $a_2 > 0$, that's
$$ \eqalign{ Y - a_1 X &< a_1 + b_1\cr
             Y - a_2 X &> b_2 - 1\cr} $$

Comment: Thanks, great exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Btw, hello there fellow Israel, Israel lastname here too, always thinking to check what my genealogy is. /sorry for offtopic.

Comment: @Artemix If you're interested in genealogy, find me on Facebook or Ancestry.com or MyHeritage.com and message me there.

Comment: Done, on Facebook.